# How to change data in a table with a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have a button where on click it changes a string value from null to any other text (for example 'yes'). I have a button in the view that calls an update method in the controller but I don't know what to put inside that update method.

In the view, this is the button ('item' refers to model, 'Activated' refers to a string column in that model which has a default value of null)

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectMVC2.Models.ApplicationUser>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

@if (item.Activated == null)
        {


            using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "User", new { id = item.Id })){
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <td class="button btn-default" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Activate" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </td>
            }
        }
        else if (item.Activated == "Yes")
        {
            <td class="c" align="center">
                Activated already
            </td>
        }
```

I have the method in my controller

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    ApplicationDbContext context;


    public UserController()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var User = context.Users.ToList();
        return View(User);
    }
    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index")
    }
}
```

In the method what should I put that will allow for the change to happen? Please if anyone can help, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to updated your model itself:

```
public ActionResult Update()
{
    var users = context.Users.ToList();
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
       user.Activated = "Yes";
    }
    context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

However, this changes are persisted so if you come back to the page again you'll still see `user.Activated = "Yes"`. If you need something temporary, I would suggest to use following code.

```
public ActionResult Update()
{
    var users = context.Users.ToList();
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
       user.Activated = "Yes";
    }
    return View("Index", users);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - The activate button works now (it changes the string data from null to "yes" however it does it for all the users. I want the button to work for each user so if I activate one user another user does not get activated

Comment: Then you should have a button for each individual user or a checkbox for selection.

Comment: I will try something out later, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop to take advantage of model binding to a collection.

This is accomplished by using an indexing expression e.g. `Model[i]`.

Add a `HiddenFor` to tell the controller which users need to be activated.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
{
    var item = Model[i];
    @if (item.Activated == null)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "User", new { id = item.Id }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(_ => Model[i].Id)
            <td class="button btn-default" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Activate" class="btn btn-default" />
            </td>
        }
    }
    else if (item.Activated == "Yes")
    {
        <td class="c" align="center">
            Activated already
        </td>
    }
```

The update method now accepts a collection of users to activate.

```
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> usersToActivate)
{
    // Are there any user to active?
    if (usersToActivate == null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    var userIds = usersToActivate.Select(u => u.Id).ToList();
    var usersToUpdate = context.Users.Where(user => userIds.Contains(user.Id));

    foreach (var userToUpdate in usersToUpdate)
    {
        userToUpdate.activated = "Yes";
    }

    context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however the indexing expression does not work. The model im using for the users is ApplicationUser which is the default for users and it cannot apply the indexing

Comment: You may need to convert the model into a List in order to index.